# Manual junit startup

Tags: java, junit

I am trying to understand an architecture of junit(particularly junit5 jupiter for now). I want to get out of an annotation view and run my tests, as if there were no integration with build tools. I am searching for examples of manual setup for tests execution. For example like I run any java application(even in spring boot I manually declare entry point in main)

How can I do this? I will be happy, if you show examples for junit4 too.

Comment: You're just asking how to start a JUnit 4/5 test from command line?

Comment: Not the command line, but from my main entry point in main class. I imagine this as `new JuniitTestRunner(tests).run()`